# Set JQuery Mobile slider value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on a watch face for Pebble, and I have added a configuration screen that's supposed to populate the config values from storage. I'm trying to select the slider option based on URL parameters.

```
var invert = 'off';
var hour = 'on';

$("#invert").val(invert).slider("refresh");
$("#hour").val(hour).slider("refresh");
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonwgeorge/by52c/2/) example. For simplicity sake I've removed the function to get the URL parameters, but the code is basically the same.

For some reason, I can't get the sliders to refresh on page load based on what the variables are set to. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only mistake was not giving proper id to your hour slider

Instead of this:

```
<select name="hour" id="24hour" data-role="slider">
```

should be this:

```
<select name="hour" id="hour" data-role="slider">
```

Working fine now: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/by52c/3/

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Comment: Welcome. Don't worry, it happens to everyone hehe